# SwiftUI: Reinitialize after popover.show

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am writing a MacOS (10.15 Catalina) application using a popover. The main ContentView includes a custom view with a simple toggle:

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var popover=NSPopover()
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        self.popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)

        self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: 18)
        
        if let statusBarButton = self.statusBarItem.button {
            statusBarButton.title = "☰"
            statusBarButton.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
        }

    func show() {
        let statusBarButton=self.statusBarItem.button!
        self.popover.show(relativeTo: statusBarButton.bounds, of: statusBarButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
    }
    func hide() {
        popover.performClose(nil)
    }
    @objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        self.popover.isShown ? hide() : show()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Test("Hello")
        //  more stuff
    }
}

struct Test: View {
    var message: String
    @State private var clicked: Bool = false

    init(message: String) {
        self.message = message
        _clicked = State(initialValue: false)
        print("init")
    }

    var body: some View {
        return HStack {
            Text(message)
            Button("Click") {
                self.clicked = true
            }
            if !self.clicked {
                Text("Before")
            }
            else {
                Text("After")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to reinitialize some data in custom view whenever the popup reappears. So, in this example, `clicked` should reset to `false`. I have tried every combination of `@Binding` and `@State` variables I could find in my many searches, but nothing appears to work. It appears that `.onAppear()` only fires the first time.

The `init()` function is there because in my application I also need to include additional content and code. In this example, I have tried to use it to initialize the `clicked` state variable, but, though the `print()` function does print, the variable doesn’t seem to get reset.

How can I reinitialize the `@State` variable?

Answer (score 0):

To initialize state in init you should not initialize it as property (because properties are initialised *before* init and state is initialised only once), so

```
struct Test: View {
    var message: String
    @State private var clicked: Bool     // << here, only declare

    init(message: String) {
        self.message = message
        _clicked = State(initialValue: false)   // << then this works
        print("init")
    }
    
    // ... other code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still find that `clicked` seems to be `true` in that the `After` text still shows after the first time.

Comment: It is not clear at which moment (or at which event) you need to reset `clicked`, so code is missing - could you clarify?

Comment: I have included a very brief version of the AppDelegate. The idea is when I show the popover again, the `Test` view should be reset.

Comment: Try to recreate it with `Test("Hello").id(UUID())`

Comment: That did the trick. I can guess what’s going on there, but is that a dirty trick? Is it possible to incorporate that trick inside the `Test` view so that it stands alone?